# Nginx multiple server blocks

Tags: nginx, domain, web, redirection

Im having an issue trying to configure `Nginx` to work with `gitlab` and some other sites I have.

I have **foo.com** that points to my server. **bar.foo.com** also points to my server. 
I'm trying to have gitlab on **bar.foo.com**, and another website on **foo.com**

I thought I could easily do this using server blocks and server_names, but this doesnt appear to be correct.

What I tried doing is defining 3 different server blocks, with different server names. But this doesnt work. What happens is that when I try accessing `foo.com` I end up on `bar.foo.com` which is gitlab.

I keep just ending up on gitlab whatever I try doing. So I then thought maybe the root should go into the location folders, but that doesnt appear to change anything.

In my sites-enabled I currently have 3 files : gitlab, website1  and website2

Any help would be appreciated.

here is the `gitlab` configuration file

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name bar.foo.com www.bar.foo.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  #root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
   root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;
     # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Here is the second file :

```
 server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.com www.foo.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    #root /var/www/users;

    location / {
        root /var/www/users;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

The third file is very similar to the second, so ill not bother posting it.

Comment: Did you reload nginx and clear your browser cache?

Comment: should be working that way...as you mentioned, server_name is the important directive and it looks good.

Comment: I restarted nginx. It should make the distinction between git.foo.com and foo.com shouldnt it ? Could it be because of the upstream ?